Calculate $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2} \, dz$
Calculate $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2} \, dz$
I want to verify that the following method is a right way to go about this:
By Rouche, $17z^8$ and the denominator have the same number of zeroes interior to $|z|=1$. As they both have $8$ complex roots, this covers all of them. Thus, we can expand the circle as large as we would like and retain the same value. That is,
$$|I_1| = \left|\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2} \, dz\right|$$
$$=|I_R| = \left|\int_{|z|=R} \frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2} \, dz\right|$$
$$\leq \int_{|z|=R} \frac{R^6}{Rz^8-7R^4+2R^2-5R+2} \, |dz|$$
$$= \frac{2\pi R}{Rz^2-\frac{7}{R^2}+\frac{2}{R^4}-\frac{5}{R^5}+\frac{2}{R^2}}$$
As $|I_1| = |I_R|$ for every $R>0$, then as $R$ grows large, we must have $|I_1| = 0$ and hence the entire integral is $0$.

If there are no poles inside the path, this theorem shows the integral is $0$.

An analogous line of reasoning is to substitute $w=1/w$.

Yes, you are right. There are $8$ zeros $z_1,z_2,\cdots,,z_8$ in the $|z|<1$ for $f(z)=17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2$.
Another method to compute the integral is Residue theorem:
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2} \, dz\\
=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^8Res\left(\frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2},z_k\right)\\
=-2\pi iRes\left(\frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2},\infty\right)\\
=2\pi i\lim_{z\to\infty}z\cdot\frac{z^6}{17z^8-7z^4+2iz^2-5z+2}\\
=0.$$

@Grigor Hakobyan Yes, you are right ,the third line is  residue at infinity! Actually, you method is nice and my method is just your version in "residue" language! There is no essential differences.
